# references in c++ with static

Tags: c++, reference, static

Below is a output question.I am not able to understand why its answer is 30.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;                     //namespace std is being used                      

int &fun()
{                            
    static int x = 10;                   //x is static
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();           //fun() called
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:30
Can anybody tell why output is coming to be 30 and also can explain the role of static keyword

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: What output did you expect? Why?

Answer (score 3):

> In computer programming, a static variable is a variable that has been allocated statically—whose lifetime or "extent" extends across the entire run of the program

```
void foo()
{
    int a = 10;
    static int b = 10;

    a++;
    b++;

    std::cout << "a : " << a << " , b : " << b << std::endl;
}
```

> A reference variable is an alias, that is, another name for an already existing variable. Once a reference is initialized with a variable, either the variable name or the reference name may be used to refer to the variable.

```
int a = 4;
int b = a;
int &c = a;

c++;

std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl; //4
std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl; //5
std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl; //5

/* Becaues c is a refence to a, it means that
a and c are just different names to the same memory location
so updating either one updates the actual value in memory
*/

a++;
std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;  //6
std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;  //6

//consider the function below:
int &bar()
{
    static int a = 5;
    std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl;
    return a;
}
```

Testing the two:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        foo();
    //for every call of foo():
    //memory allocation for a is created and deleted when a goes out of scope
    //memoery allocation for b extends through out the life of the program

   //bar() returns a reference to "a" i.e
   int reference_to_a = bar(); //prints 5
   reference_to_a = 30; 
   bar();  //prints 30

   bar() = 50;  //prints 30 and later assigns 50 to the reference returned.
   bar();       //prints 50

}
```

Comment: "whose lifetime or extent extends across the entire run of the program" - is not exactly correct. The lifetime may not begin until the first call of the function containing the static variable. And for a program with multiple static variables of class type, their lifetime ends in the opposite order of their constructors running.

Answer (score 1):

`static` make the variable persist across function calls.

which means `static int x = 10;`  will be executed once when `func` is called for the first time.

```
int static_test()
{
    static int x = 10;
    x++;
    return x;
} 

static_test(); // first call will return 11
static_test(); // second call will return 12 because the value of x ( was saved and was then incremented)
static_test(); // third call will return 13
```

Now, you need to understand what reference are. To understand what reference are you need to understand pointers. I am guessing you will easily find some website explaining those two.

Comment: Or OP can just just look at @jafar 's answer which covers it quite nicely.

Comment: @user4581301 this site does not have a restriction that nobody can post an answer if there is already an answer...

Comment: @MattMcNabb Not the point I was trying to make. Setpenre answered first by about 5 minutes, but declined to cover the effect of `&`. Jafar's answer filled that hole.

Comment: can anybody answer why output is coming to be 30,i already know meaning of static and references

Comment: @RohanBlagan, i've edited the answer to explain better why the answer is 30.

Answer (score 1):

**case 1:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;                     //namespace std is being used                      

int &fun()
{                            
    int x = 10;                   //x is static
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();           //fun() called
    return 0;
}
```

Here, in the call fun(), we are declaring a local variable `int x`, which goes out of scope once it returns from fun(). 
so, in the line `cout << fun()` a new variable is declared and address of the new variable is returned.

case 2:

```
static int x = 10;
```

here, since variable 'x' is static, it can be initialized only once. i.e., the first time x is initialized to 5 and then over written to 30.

now when you are making the function call subsequent times, `static int x = 5` is ignored. Hence, it returns the value `30`